# What does 'a' mean in JVM instructions like 'aload' or 'areturn'?

Tags: jvm, terminology

What does 'a' mean in JVM instructions like 'aload' or  'areturn'?
I know they operate on references, but why are they named 'aload', 'astore', etc instead of 'rload', 'rstore', etc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe historically 'a' stands for 'address' since the times when an object reference was just a plain address into the heap.

The support for this idea can be found in the sources of [K virtual machine](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-141974.html) by Sun Microsystems - one of the first Java Virtual Machines for Java ME. The sources can be downloaded from [CLDC 1.1 RI page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javame-419430.html#J2MECLDC-1.1-WINUNIX-G-F).

The fragment from `kvm/VmCommon/src/bytecodes.c`:

```
#if STANDARDBYTECODES
SELECT(ILOAD)            /* Load integer from local variable */
        unsigned int index = ip[1];
        pushStack(lp[index]);
DONE(2)
#endif

...

#if STANDARDBYTECODES
SELECT(ALOAD)            /* Load address from local variable */
        unsigned int index = ip[1];
        pushStack(lp[index]);
DONE(2)
#endif
```

[here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javame-419430.html#J2MECLDC-1.1-WINUNIX-G-F)

Comment: It also matches the fact that the instruction `astore` can store values of type *returnaddress* (up to Java 6)…

Comment: So what about `aaload` meaning ?

Comment: @shaoyihe for first 'a' for 'address', the second - for 'array'. The instructions loads a reference from the array.